# Pokemon Go: Power up a low CP Venusaur or wait to evolve a high CP Bulbasaur?

Tags: pokemon-go

I woke up very early in the morning today to try and be more productive, and when I checked my phone there was a Venusaur nearby! I didn't hesitate to go outside and find him. I was a little disappointed when I did. He had 32 CP (sigh).

I have 4 more Bulbasaurs, my strongest with a 299 CP. Is powering up my Venusaur or waiting to find more Bulbasaurs to evolve the strongest one the ideal choice?

(I'm having a hard time finding Bulbasaurs) :/
By the way, I'm level 13

Comment: In this scenario, that venusaur is so low that it would probably take more candy to power it up all the way than it would to just save your candies

Comment: I'd save to evolve as well, not worth upgrading a low cp high evolution.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on whether you want to spend more candy or more stardust.

Evolving a bulbasaur to a venusaur takes 125 candy. This means catching 32 bulbasaurs. Unless you find a place where they spawn often, this will take a long time. On the plus side, you might find an even better bulbasaur this way

Levelling the venusaur to the level of bulbasaur will probably take about 30 candy, but also about 20,000 stardust. This may seem a lot, but at least you can earn that catching pidgeys. It depends whether you have something else you need that stardust for.

Comment: You also have to consider that it takes some candies to power up too.

Comment: Yeah, spending all that stardust on a single pokemon is something I want to avoid. I'll be looking for a place where they spawn of often. Thanks!

Comment: The whole catching 32 bulbasaurs to candy thing isn't exactly true.  You get a ton of candy from hatching a particular pokémon.  If you focus on a lot of incubation on the properly sized egg, you may end up getting a ton of candies from a single hatched bulbasaur egg.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the answer regarding Candy vs Stardust.  You should also consider the current IV values and Attack moves of the Venusaur that you caught.  If it is a particularly gifted specimen, then you might want to stick with it over the possibility of going through the trouble of catching a much higher CP Bulbasaur and evolving it only to find that its final evolution got a bad roll on moves and you wasted a bunch of candy for nothing.  Move set is a big factor in whether or not to stick with one pokemon over another.

Comment: Didn't had that on my mind! I'll check those out first then.